# Does distribution with these properties exist?

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, hazard, mathematical-statistics

Let X be a random variable with support that covers 0 (i.e. r.v. can take both positive and negative values) and positive mean: $EX>0$. Let $X^+=max(X,0)$.

Question: for which class of distributions $\frac{E(X^+)}{P(X\ge0)}$ is a decreasing function of $EX$?

Is there a single distribution with this property? (at least for some values of $EX$)

Using direct differentiation w.r.t. EX, I came up with the following question: is there a distribution for which
$\frac{E(X^+)}{P(X\ge0)}> \frac{1-F(0}{f(0)}$? (alternatively:
$\frac{E(X^+)}{(P(X\ge 0))^2}> \frac{1}{f(0)}$)

Comment: Do you require $X$ to be a continuous random variable?

Comment: ideally yes, not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by  "Is there a single distribution with this property"? For a single distribution, $E(X^+)/P(X\geq 0)$ and $E(X)$ are constants, so it is not meaningful to ask whether the first is a decreasing function of the latter.